# Alpha Over node doesn't work correctly?

Tags: compositing-nodes, transparency

Here's the first output:

[image]

The second:

[image]

And after using Alpha Over node:

[image]

Blend file:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the **Convert Premul** option.

[image: Convert Premul]

Comment: Could you please add some more information, maybe explain what *convert premul* does?

Comment: @PGmath I actually [have asked that question myself](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38459/compositing-when-to-use-premultiplied-alpha). From cegaton's comment there I was able to understand it better, but I don't feel I can explain it well. I hammered out this answer here in a span of a few minutes while on a short train ride, hoping to at least solve OP's problem even if I couldn't elaborate. Feel free to add something to the answer if you like.