# Masking problems

Tags: node-editor, masking

I am working with masking.
Here is my node setting with the mask.
[image: nodes]

And here is my node settings[image: node settings]

And what am i getting is this.

[image]

I tried invert node and many settings. It just doesnt work. Where am i going wrong

Comment: Please explain what are you tringin to acheve. Readable screenshots would also be nice.

Comment: Try lower opacity, I guess 1 is pure white, so Alpha over node is kind of replacing image rather than overlaying (due to you haven't got transparency on image with "magic force" ) Or try ADD mixRGB node instead of Alpha over - it would be a bit brighter, but black values will not appear on the hand.

Comment: There is a energy ball in my hand and i want my fingers to mask it. But only two this happen. 1 )the one mentioned in pic  and 2) oe else only the tge energy ball and the mask is getting rendered(only the part of image covered by mask and the animation)

Comment: Please use screenshots taken with the print screen key on your keyboard, not photos of the display

Comment: In blender you can make a screen shot by pressing Ctrl+F3 and saving the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The *Over* operation of a cg object using a mask

Make sure the cg render has a transparent background.

[image]
[Sorry the labeling is switched, right is *Internal* and left is *cycles.*]

The render preview will show a checkered background, indicating **transparency**.

[image]

The **mask** (created in the image editor) can also by viewed, by connecting its output to a viewer node in the compositor.

[image]

For the easiest *over* operation, our mask is the "wrong way around". This means, we'll have to *invert* it. Add a [*Color >] **Invert*** node after the mask.

[image: mask invert nodes]

---

#### Method to be used with any number of masks.

If you want to use multiple mask nodes, you are not going to be able to use the above node setup.

For that, **unpremultiply** image, alter the alpha (subtraction, max, cojoint-over, etc), **premultiply** it. This method is far more superior but also much more complex. Read up on [premultiplication](http://www.spherevfx.com/written-training/miscellaneous-written-training/understanding-premultiplied-images/)!

[image]

---

Premultiplication related: [Popcorn question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/64322/30849), [Green screen question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/45877/30849), [Alpha nodes assumes alpha (so smart, wow)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/46151/30849), [when to convert to premultiplied](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/38459/30849), [Worst answer ever](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/40594/30849)

[image]