# Jagged edges in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, edges

[edit]

I've altered my node-tree like suggested in the other post.
It changed a cluster of maybe 8 pixels.
The solution I'm looking for will result in straight edges without jaggies.
Blurring the edges is not what I'm looking for.
I need crisp sharp edges on the car.
Perhaps these new images make for a better example.
Again, thank you for your time and effort!

Cheers!

[image]
[image]

[original post]

Hello people of this fine community!

I'm having a problem with jagged edges on the geometry of the roof of the car in cycles render and I have no clue how to smooth them out.

Render samples are set to 1000.

I have 3 render layers:
1 with the car, 1 with geometry acting as a shadowcatcher and 1 with the background image.
There's 1 big lightsource.

When blender is busy rendering the geometry of the car and there's still a transparent background, the roof of the car is smoothed out.
The jagged edges only become visible when all renders are put together in the composite at the end.

I actually quite like it. Sentiment for oldschool games I guess but my projectleader is not having it..

[image: nodes]

Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to enable *antialiasing* for all Mask-Id nodes and see if that helps. Also this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/67371/31447 is a great one (when it comes to render layers).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, alas the antialiasing for all Mask-Id nodes sadly doesn't make it better. Also, I've been staring myself blind, I never noticed these checkboxes on the Mask-Id nodes xD

Could it have something to do with not having a very good graphics card in this machine?

Comment: This could be caused by the mishandling of alpha types. [See this.](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38459/compositing-when-to-use-premultiplied-alpha/44219#44219)

Comment: Hmm, okay but I don't use an alpha over node.
I'm only a beginner and I don't know if I'm mishandling alpha types and if I am I didn't mean to hurt anyone.

Comment: My apologies for creating a duplicate post David.
Thanks for pointing it out.
I'll try and figure out how to implement this into my own node-tree

Comment: ok I *think* see the issue. Is there any reason you can't just use the alpha for adding the background in?

Comment: I'm willing to try anything at this point.
Can you draw out how to connect the nodes?