# Nodes issue, shadow catcher is visible

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

My [earlier issue](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75173/jagged-edges-in-cycles) was a problem with jagged edges.
I found that if I remove the ID Mask Index: 1 output from the Mix Fac input, the edges are crisp, but the shadow catcher mesh becomes visible, see below.

[image]
[image]

Requested by [Mentalist](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/2952/mentalist):
[image]
[image]

Now I can't figure out how to get the shadowcatcher to be invisible again.
Can someone help figure this out?

Comment: Can you show us what the output from ID Mask Index 2 looks like?

Comment: Yes hold on! I hope this is what you mean.

Comment: That is exactly what I mean. Thanks! I'll give this some thought.

Comment: Sure. Oops...I should have asked you for the output from ID Mask 1 too, since you said that one was working. Can you also show that for comparison?

Comment: Yeah just a sec

Comment: I have questions. 1. Did you create this following a tutorial, and if so what tutorial? 2. Are you aware of [the new Shadow Catcher feature](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SiU46VHzEnY)? It might save you from hassle and headache.

Comment: Yes! And yes! But I for some reason can't get that version running at work. This is the tutorial https://youtu.be/wjWoglMYXBE

Answer (score 1):

What I've realized, after watching [the tutorial](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/render-onto-photo-background/), putting this together myself, and then looking at your node setup again, is that by disconnecting ID Mask: Index 1 you have broken your node setup. And with the Mix Node's Factor set to 1 there is no meaning in having a Mix Node at all (combining 0% of one image with 100% of another). Sliding it to anything less than 1 won't help either, because it needs the ID Mask to mask your car object back in.

If I were you, I would revisit [your original problem](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75173/jagged-edges-in-cycles) with eliminating the jagged edges instead of trying to hack the node setup.

Comment: Now, I realize the answer of "it's broken because you broke it" doesn't help you get your project done, so I'll offer an idea: If you have jagged edges and are unable to pin down the cause in time to meet your deadline, consider taking a brute force approach, like rendering at double the final resolution and then scaling down. That's just one idea I can offer, without having studied your original problem. It's not a good way because your render time will go way up, but it might be faster than spending days troubleshooting your compositing setup.

Comment: Hey man!
I tried the clamping, which sadly didn't work. I also tried clamp on the mix node after the multiply node, and then tried different combinations but nothing changed.
Then I tried to get on http://graphicall.org/1200 which took about 7 minutes to load.. I think there's something wrong with their hosting. Anyway, the experimental version with shadowcatcher works!
It's so easy! :)
Thanks for your help and time everyone, especially Mr. Mentalist!

Comment: @RobertZuman Great! I'm glad you found a solution. Examining this has been interesting/educational for me as well. Cheers.

Comment: :D Cheers man, happy endeavours!