# Why in Blender VSE it adds a border to scaled or moved image?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Why adding `Transform` (moving or scaling) to an image in VSE adds a border to it (image)?

If `position` and `scale` of Transform is unchanged - then there is no border.

Example:

[image: Not scaled]

With Transform applied:

[image: Transform, scaled]

It is also visible while rendering.

**Update:** When I set in image proerties `Color space` to anything but `sRGB` (`Raw` for example) these borders go away.

[image]

Comment: It maybe a problem with the alpha of the image. What blend type have you chosen for mixing the image strip with the background?

Comment: Blend: Alpha Over. I also tried png and jpg files

Comment: I agree that it is likely to be an alpha issue. Try rendering it out and examining it in an image editor to see if there is some alpha on the outermost pixels. This sometimes happens when images are resized. If it's happening with JPEG too it is occurring in your compositing, not the final file. JPEG does not support transparency.

Comment: One possible cause *could* be the mishandling of premultiplied versus straight alpha, somewhere in your node setup. [More info here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38459/compositing-when-to-use-premultiplied-alpha)

Comment: can you please upload your .blend with the issue via this link and attach it to your post?
http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: @JanKadeřábek done

Comment: oh, but that image is missing, you can use File -> External Data -> Pack all into .blend

Comment: `No new files have been packed`. Don't know what's wrong.

Comment: I think Blender does not pack files at all if working in VSE only. https://developer.blender.org/T42522

Comment: Quick workaround, try adding a mask via the strip modifier panel. Just draw a box shape in tje uv/image editor. This should replace the alpha channel. Otherwise if your image is just black and white on a whitr background use an add blend type.